# Relation between Users and Dinners in Nerddinner project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In Nerddinner project, i see that dinners has relation to users by username if i didn't understand it wrongly. I expected that dinners would have relation to users by unique identifiers. There is no something wrong about it? If we want to change username of user so we should to consider manually update relations. Please consider old questions which asked why it is not better idea to use username as unique identifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the exact database schema in mind, but as far as I know, user management is handled by ASP.NET built-in membership facilities in the membership database.  While you can get unique ID from ASP.NET membership providers, the type of that identifier can vary across different providers (e.g. could be `Int32` in one provider and `Guid` in another as [providerUserKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152044.aspx) argument in membership API is declared of type `object`). Therefore, if you want to isolate yourself from any specific membership provider, you'd better stick to the username. It's portable.

Comment: Most of MVC projects rely on username as a primary ID ?

Comment: @Freshblood: Nope. It's a matter of personal preference. If you'd like to give a user the chance to change his username, using his name as Primary ID wouldn't be the correct choice.

Comment: It makes sense to do that if both of the following are true: 1) you are using ASP.NET membership providers that store user information in a separate database. 2) you don't have any info attached to each user in your "contents" database (i.e. you don't have a table in that database describing each user).  If the second condition is not true, you probably want to assign a primary key to that user information table and use that as your key.

Answer (score 1):

Username is a unique identifier in this example. You don't need to use int or uniqueidentifier (Guid) as the key if there is a more natural key. In this instance username is unique within the system so is a natural key for the user records.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct; the user names are used as the unique identifier that ties users to dinners (or to the RSVPs, as I recall).

It uses those values because user names must be unique already, so it is a unique ID... it's just not a numeric, auto-generated one.